# SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, struts2, hql

I am using Struts2 & Hibernate and getting below error when I searched data with string `test` but works for me when I searched with numeric `111`. I am getting this value from bean class and defined property of string type in bean class.

Below I am providing code:

```java
public String retrieveRecords() 
{    
    String empId = p.getEmpId();
    String paramValue = "";
    if(empId !=null)
        if(!(empId.isEmpty()))
        paramValue =" where b.empId="+empId;

    String empName = p.getEmployeeName();
    if(empName !=null && empName != "")
    {
        if(!(empName.isEmpty())){
        if(paramValue == "")
         paramValue =" where b.employeeName="+empName;
        else
         paramValue =paramValue + " and b.employeeName="+empName;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("=========paramvalues===="+paramValue);
    recList = (List<RequestBean>) session.createQuery("from RequestBean b"+paramValue).list();
    request.setAttribute("rec", recList);
    System.out.println("got size"+recList);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

**Bean Class:**

```java
public class RequestBean {

    private Long id;
    private String empId;
    private String employeeName;
    private String employeeType;
    private String personnalNumber;
    private String contactNumber;
    private String companyName;
    private String address;
    private String remarks;
    private String empStatus = "E";
    private Date joiningDate = null;
    private Date created;

    /************* Getters ************************/

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }

    public String getEmployeeType() {
        return employeeType;
    }

    public String getPersonnalNumber() {
        return personnalNumber;
    }

    public String getContactNumber() {
        return contactNumber;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getRemarks() {
        return remarks;
    }

    public Date getJoiningDate() {
        return joiningDate;
    }

    public String getEmpStatus() {
        return empStatus;
    }

    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

   /******************* Setters ***************************/

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setEmpId(String empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }
    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }
    public void setEmployeeType(String employeeType) {
        this.employeeType = employeeType;
    }
    public void setPersonnalNumber(String personnalNumber) {
        this.personnalNumber = personnalNumber;
    }
    public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) {
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
    }
    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
        this.remarks = remarks;
    }
    public void setJoiningDate(Date joiningDate) {
        this.joiningDate = joiningDate;
    }
    public void setEmpStatus(String empStatus) {
        this.empStatus = empStatus;
    }
    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

}
```

**Mapping:**

```xml
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.ims.bean.RequestBean" table="EMPDETAILS">

<id name="id" column="id">
   <generator class="increment"/>
</id>

<!-- <property name="id"     column="id" /> -->
<property name="empId"  column="empId"/>
<property name="employeeName"  column="empName"/>
<property name="employeeType"  column="empType"/>
<property name="personnalNumber"  column="personnalNum"/>
<property name="contactNumber"  column="contactNo"/>
<property name="companyName"  column="empCompanyName"/>
<property name="address"  column="address"/>
<property name="remarks"  column="remarks"/>
<property name="joiningDate"  column="joiningDate"/>
<property name="empStatus"  column="empStatus"/>
<property name="created"  column="created"/>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Error:**

```java
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:90)
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2231)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
    org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
    org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    com.ims.DAO.RequestControllerDAO.retrieveRecords(RequestControllerDAO.java:60)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor76.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:891)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1293)
    ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:117)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:108)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1369)
    ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:90)
    ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:494)
    ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:458)
```

Comment: Obligatory read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.

Comment: What does the query end up looking like? Is `empName` quoted? Could you end up with `where ... where ...` which is not legal?

Comment: You should compare strings using `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()`. These are wrong `empName != ""`, `paramValue == ""`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `SQLGrammarException` is thrown because the SQL query generated by Hibernate has wrong SQL syntax. The way you built the query is wrong, you shouldn't concatenate values (especially string values) to the result query, because such code is vulnerable for possible [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack. Instead, you can use parameters in the query string

```java
String empId = p.getEmpId();
String paramValue = "";
if (empId !=null && !empId.isEmpty())
    paramValue = " where b.empId=:empId";
String empName = p.getEmployeeName();
if (empName !=null && !empName.isEmpty()) {
    if (paramValue == "")
     paramValue =" where b.employeeName=:empName";
    else
     paramValue =paramValue + " and b.employeeName=:empName"; 
}       
System.out.println("=========paramvalues===="+paramValue);
Query query = session.createQuery("from RequestBean b"+paramValue);
//now set parameter values
if(empId !=null && !empId.isEmpty())
  query.setParameter("empId", empId);
if(empName !=null && !empName.isEmpty())
  query.setParameter("empName", empName);
recList = (List<RequestBean>) query.list();
```

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/struts-2-tutorials/, after you can try links from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27686588/573032) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your hql to sql converted query is generating:

```
    "where employeeName=Name"
```

while it should be generating:

```
    "where employeeName='Name'".
```

So your hql should be :

```
    "where b.employeeName= ' " +empName+ " ' ";
```

Note : You don't need to do that for integer values, only applies to String variables.

Comment: While this answer could fix the error it's not a good practice because introduces security vulnerabilities (SQL injection). See RomanC's answer.

Comment: Yeah, don't do this! Please.